# Shall we avoid writing static methods in our java code for better testability?

Tags: java, static

I was prefer using static methods in my java code, since I think they are <s>"functional"</s>"stateless" and has less side-effect. So there may be some helper classes and methods like this:

```
public class MyHelper {
    public static Set<String> array2set(String[] items) { ... }
    public static List<String> array2list(String[] items) { ...}
    public static String getContentOfUrl(String url) {
        // visit the url, and return the content of response
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    public void doSomething() {
        String[] myarray = new String[]{ "aa","bb"};
        Set<String> set = MyHelper.array2set(myarray);
        String content = MyHelper.getContentOfUrl("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

But my friend says we should avoid defining such static utility methods, since we call them directly in our code, it will be hard to mock them or test them if they have external dependencies. He thinks the code should be:

```
public class ArrayHelper {
    public Set<String> array2set(String[] items) { ... }
    public List<String> array2list(String[] items) { ...}
}
public class UrlHelper {
    public String getContentOfUrl(String url) {
        // visit the url, and return the content of response
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    private final ArrayHelper arrayHelper;
    private final UrlHelper urlHelper;
    public MyApp(ArrayHelper arrayHelper, UrlHelper urlHelper) {
        this.arrayHelper = arrayHelper;
        this.urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        String[] myarray = new String[]{ "aa","bb"};
        Set<String> set = arrayHelper.array2set(myarray);
        String content = urlHelper.getContentOfUrl("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

In this way, if we want to write unit tests for `MyApp`, we can just mock the `ArrayHelper` and `UrlHelper` and pass them to the constructor of `MyApp`.

I agree totally about the `UrlHelper` part of his opinion, since the origin static code make `MyApp` untestable.

But I have a little confused about the `ArrayHelper` part, since it doesn't depend on any external resources and the logic will be very simple. Shall we avoid using static methods at this case too?

And when to use static methods? Or just avoid using it as much as possible?

---

update:

We are using "TDD" in our development, so the testability of a class often is the most important concern for us.

And I just replace the word "functional" with "stateless" in the first sentence since the that's real what I meant.

Comment: Java is not a functional language. It is a OOP language, so I suggest you use object orientated programming or use a functional language.

Comment: Static methods should be stateless while instance methods are mostly used to alter the state of the instance.

Comment: sometimes i throw useful logic functions into a util.java type class. However for array converters, I would have this as part of the instance, since any memory associated will get cleaned up when the instance is destroyed. It is safer to avoid static as soon as things get complicated or lots of memory moves around.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, thank you for pointing this, I just found the word I want to use is "stateless", which is better to express my idea

Comment: I would think Iterator or Adapter would be the OOP answer?

Comment: @PeterLawrey As of Java 8 that characterisation of Java will not be as clear anymore.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Very true, IMHO it will be a while before it really makes sense to do functional programming in Java.  The syntax is still pretty clunky (the streams part, not the closures) and the execution much slower.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guess the only real use case is seamless parallelisation, which seems to be the primary motivator behind that API.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik IMHO Parallelism is over used by developer who don't understand that it can create more overhead than benefit.  Yes, all the CPU light up as busy, but the program is slower.  Now there is an easy way to make all the CPUs busy, not sure that is a good thing. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey But the only way to push performance today and in the future will be parallelisation; however it will take quite a while until everything is designed around that scheme, and until then there will be many lines of wishful thinking around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beware of overengineering.

In your specific example, you either *do* or *don't* have a mockability issue. Since you are asking this in general, I'll assume you don't have a specific issue at the moment.

The general argument is that `static` methods are simpler and therefore the preferred choice, whenever there is a choice. A would-be instance method must first prove itself of needing to be an instance method.

If this was my project, I would defer any makeovers into instance methods until such a moment where the need for that became clear and present.

Comment: I was trying to use `static` methods as much as possible before, but I have to agree that the solution of my friend is much easier to write unit tests. And we have to write unit tests for every non-private methods.

Comment: A I understand from your question, you *don't* see an issue with array-helper methods. If you say testing is easier with instance methods in all cases, then what exactly is your question?

Comment: Will your solution be: 1. static methods for `ArrayHelper` 2. Instance methods for `UrlHelper`?

Comment: In the situation as you have described it, yes.

Comment: Good, this is what I prefer too :)

Answer (score 16):

You'll probably never want to mock a method that converts an array to a list (or set), and this method doesn't need any state and doesn't depend on any environment, so a static method looks fine to me.

Just like the standard `Arrays.asList()` (which you should probably use).

On the other hand, accessing an external URL is typically the sort of thing that you want to be able to mock easily, because not mocking it would

- make the test an integration test
- require to have this external URL up every time you run your tests, which you probably can't guarantee
- require to have this external URL return exactly what you want it to return in your test (including errors if you want to test the event of an error).

Comment: The method `MyHelper.getContentOfUrl("http://google.com");` on the other hand is problematic, since it accesses external state.

Comment: So for the `UrlHelper` one, I should avoid using static methods, right?

Comment: Right. Accessing an external URL is typically the sort of thing that you want to be able to mock in a test.

Comment: The broader answer is that you do not need to, and should not, mock everything execept the class under test when unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

Static means you can call the method without instantiating the class. Its good if you want to package your code into a class and you have a function that just does some logic or something basic.

Just don't use a static function to try and edit member variables in the class (obviously).

Personally I think its fine to use the static function, since it is stateless.

Comment: Thanks for the word "stateless", that's what I want to express in my first sentence. (It was "functional")

Answer (score 1):

Static methods should be used by answering the question *"is this method a functionality of a specific instance?"*.

You shouldn't decide about a `static` method according to tests, you should do it according to design. Your examples doesn't need an instance because it makes no sense. So `static` is the better choice. You can always wrap these methods inside specific tester classes to do your tests.

The only situation in which a self-contained functionality is not static is just when you want to provide multiple implementation, so that you are forced to avoid `static` because you need inheritance.

Comment: I agree the point of "according to design", but we have to write unit-tests for them, but the static methods depend on external resources are hard to test

Answer (score 1):

I often use static methods:

- for factory methods (explicitly named constructors)
- to provide a functional layer above an object-oriented layer, to compose the objects
- and sometimes for general-purpose functions (Apache Commons has many good examples of this)

I never use "singletons" (static objects) and methods that *refer to* static objects because they are a complete headache to test and reuse. I also avoid hardcoding anything into a static method that could feasibly need to be changed. Sometimes I will provide multiple methods - one with all the dependencies as parameters and others, with fewer parameters, that call the more flexible method with some default (hardcoded) values.

Comment: Your idea is very similar with my friend's :)

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Math is static which is a good example. I thought statics are not beeing garbage collected and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Remember math uses lots of primitive types. You are right about garbage collection I think. Static won't get destoyed along with the instance.

Comment: `java.lang.Math` is just like the `ArrayHelper` example in my question. But I confused on the `UrlHelper` one

Answer (score -4):

No.

As mentioned by Peter Lawrey in the comment for the question, Java is all about object oriented programming. While certain functional aspects are doable and being put into eg. Java 8, at its core Java is not functional. `static` breaks so much of the benefits of learning how to do modern Java - not to mention all kinds of not-fun-at-all scoping problems - that there's no purpose to use them ***unless*** you're some kind of a Java wizard who really knows what happens when you use that magical keyword.

You are not a wizard. Java is not functional. If you want to be a wizard, you can learn. If you want to program in functional fashion, look into hybrid languages such as Scala or Groovy or alternatively explore the fully functional world, eg. Clojure.

Comment: There is a place for static, you don't have to be a wizard to know it. But I agree, "avoid unless you have a reason to use" is a good ideology. Also Java is practically the definition of OOP.

Comment: "functional java" is really not the point in this question, sorry ~